# Unable to use helpers in fancybox2-rails gem because of errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, fancybox, fancybox-2

I'm trying to get the fancybox2 to work correctly on my RoR app. I've tried the gem and just placing the files directly in my assets directory, but I can't get the helpers to work.

Now the thumbs (genereted by the helper) dont show up.
Also, the overlays dont seem to be transparent when the cursus is over it, as they should be. See images [1](http://f.cl.ly/items/0Y0c222I112M3p2y0P2S/Screen%20Shot%202013-01-30%20at%2017.13.48%20.png) and [2](http://f.cl.ly/items/1o2m2p1Y0U3b0e3p1p44/Screen%20Shot%202013-01-30%20at%2017.17.09%20.png):

Question is: What am I doing wrong?

Current output is generated with the Fancybox files in the following folders:

```
/assets/stylesheets/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css
/assets/stylesheets/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css
/assets/stylesheets/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css

/assets/images/fancybox/fancybox_overlay.png
/assets/images/fancybox/blank.gif
/assets/images/fancybox/fancybox_buttons.png
/assets/images/fancybox/fancybox_loading.gif
/assets/images/fancybox/fancybox_sprite.png

/assets/javascripts/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js

/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js
/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js
/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js
```

welcome.js

```
(function() {

  $(document).ready(function() {
    return $(".fancybox-thumb").fancybox({
      prevEffect: "none",
      nextEffect: "none",
      helpers: {
        title: {
          type: "outside"
        },
        thumbs: {
          width: 75,
          height: 75
        }
      }
    });
  });

}).call(this);
```

Outputted HTML:

```
...
<link href="/assets/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="/assets/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
...
<p>
<a class='fancybox1234' href='http://.../uploads/noimage.jpg' rel='group'>
<img alt='' src='http://.../uploads/small_noimage.jpg'>
</a>
<a class='fancybox1234' href='http://.../uploads/Burgum_Hervormde_kerk.JPG' rel='group'>
<img alt='' src='http://.../uploads/small_Burgum_Hervormde_kerk.JPG'>
</a>
</p>
...
```

If you need more output or info to help me, please let me know.
Thanks!

---

EDIT: The order of the helpers indeed was the solution to get them to work. The overlays still  dont work correctly though, so I'll have to check whether the CSS is overridden somewhere. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be a hoisting problem :

The fancybox js file should be loaded **before** the helpers files so your html output, instead of this

```
<script src="/assets/fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

should be :

```
<script src="/assets/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Also check your paths to avoid 404 errors since you are loading your css files from `fancybox/helpers/` while the js files from `fancybox/` (helpers css and js files are normally under the subdir "*helpers*")

---

Regarding the black background/overlay in the `close` and `arrows` button, most likely you are using a global css rule like :

```
a:hover { 
 background-color: #000;
}
```

... so it applies to all anchors, including fancybox's (arrow/close) anchors. Avoid global declarations and use specificity instead like :

```
a.myClass:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

... or

```
#myContainer a:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Hmmm, I dont like these problems... I also use bootstrap, which must be setting the a:hover.. I also see it in its CSS: "
    a:hover {
      color: #157ab5;
      text-decoration: underline
Guess I have to figure out how to override this file in my own CSS...
For the order.. Its kinda hard to do using require_tree . Should I specify the folders separately? OR would the gem take better care of this?